# React : Uncaught Invariant Violation: ReactDOM.render(): Invalid component element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't understand why the following code produces the error in the title. I checked similar questions, but I did not find them helpful.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { createHashHistory } from 'history';

import Menu from './pages/Menu';
import BookShelf from './pages/BookShelf';
import BorrowBook from './pages/BorrowBook';

const App = React.createClass({
  contextTypes: {
    router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
  },
  render() {
    return (
        <Menu />
      );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history={browserHistory} onUpdate={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0)}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}/>
    <Route path="/menu" component={Menu} />
    <Route path="/bookshelf" component={BookShelf} />
    <Route path="/borrowbook/:bookId"  component={BorrowBook} />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('app')
));
```

Comment: Why do you have have an extra pair of parentheses around both of the arguments to ReactDOM.render?

Comment: As @Liongold said, your parens are in the wrong spot, so you're passing one argument instead of 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ReactDOM.render(( // extra parenthesis here
  <Router history={browserHistory} onUpdate={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0)}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}/>
    <Route path="/menu" component={Menu} />
    <Route path="/bookshelf" component={BookShelf} />
    <Route path="/borrowbook/:bookId"  component={BorrowBook} />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)); // extra parenthesis here
```

The extra parenthesis are making it so that you are actually passing one argument instead of two.